# Is there a way to unlocalize a Structure Group?

Tags: 2013-sp1, blueprint, structuregroups

We have a compound Component Template (CT) that has a Template Building Block (TBB) which contains a component link. When this CT was created, the Default Finish Actions had a structure group (SG) selected which existed in the same publication (Design) as the CT.

Since that original creation (3.5 years ago) someone must have accidentally localized the SG that was targeted. Publishing still works fine as they localized it to the website publication and so it exists in the context of a publish transaction.

However, if I attempt to change that CT (add/update TBBs) I cannot save the CT as Tridion will throw an error that the item doesn't exist in the Design publication it was configured for (publication 3). I obviously can't select the localized folder as it's in publication 5 and outside the scope of the Design(3)-level CT.

So, am I forced to rename the existing, localized SG and create a new parent SG linking the Default Finish Actions to it? I can't easily delete the localized SG as there are thousands of items currently published and tracked to it's tcmid (I assume I'd need to republish everything that touches it so that references are updated to the new SG's tcmid).

**Or is there some way to unlocalize a SG like you can with a component/page** (although the GUI doesn't reveal it)?

---

**UPDATE:** Nickoli Roussakov's screenshot reminded me that if the SG was localized, it should show "(Local copy)" for its publication. Mine does not which makes it looks like it was *created* in publication 5.

However, I don't see how it's possible. The "Binaries target structure group" for the default finish actions shows tcmid 3-3460-4, but the actual SG is only located in the child website publication at 5-3460-4. So, the same ID, but a different publication and NOT inherited...

Confusing. Maybe during on of our upgrades (we've done two - from 2009 > 2011 and 2011 > 2013) something went a little sideways there? If anyone has thoughts, I'd love to hear them (like can I move this child item up to the parent publication 3 somehow?), but can understand if this question just dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your TBB has a link to `tcm:3-3460-4` and you mention that doesn't exist, then somewhere along the lines something strange has happened, especially since you mention that `tcm:5-3460-4` does exist. It should be impossible to delete a parent Structure Group and also not possible to link to non existing items.

The easiest solution I can think of is to just edit the TBB on its creation level (Publication `tcm:0-3-1`) and remove the invalid TCM URI (`tcm:3-3460-4`). Then localize the TBB in the first Publication level where it is available (without knowing your BluePrint, I would have to say Publication `tcm:0-5-1` now). There you can then link to the existing Structure Group again (`tcm:5-3460-4`). As long as you are not publishing from Publication `tcm:0-3-1` there doesn't need to be a SG in the TBB set on that level.

Another solution would indeed be to create a new Structure Group at the level of the TBB, and link that instead. But that means you need to republsh everything, as multimedia content will now go to that location when published.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Bart. I was already thinking I'd do your last suggestion (create a new SG at the level of the TBB), but rename the old SG and name the new one with the old one's Directory. That way new publishes will still go to the same physical location as the existing ones (and I wouldn't have to republish the old). Do you foresee any issues with that (other than what I mentioned previously about not being able to delete the old SG until I republish everything again)?

Comment: @JStuart not really, indeed when you change directories on a SG, just make sure you republish everything inside it. For the rest it shouldn't have any impact.

Answer (score 2):

You can localize and unlocalize SGs just like any other item in Tridion.
`Right-click->Blueprinting->Unlocalize`.

[image]

If you don't see this as an available option, it is possible your rights and permissions restrict localization actions.

From your description, it is possible that the localized SG is not the problem. Have you opened your Default Finish Actions in the publication where it was created? You can't edit Templates if you've opened them in an inherited publication - they'll be read-only.

Comment: Hmm. I'm an admin and I have opened the CT from the correct publication. Your screenshot reminded me that the SG DOESN'T show "(Local copy)" so I'm mistaken that it was localized. However, when hovering over the selected SG in Default Finish Actions it shows tcmid 3-3460-4 and that is the error that is thrown (that tcmid doesn't exist). That SG DOES exist at 5-3460-4 in a child publication which led me to believe it was a localization issue. So I guess now the question would be "how did that happen" - the SG existed in pub 3 originally but now it only exists in pub 5 (not inherited)...?